# CSV Loading Problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I try to load a CSV file into QGIS. The file contains a list of points in decimal degree format without E, W, S, or N letters, like 35.876528, 045.982671.

When I add it as a delimited layer, it loads all the points, but on a very small scale near point zero south of Ivory Coast. The distribution of the points are correct on that scale, but are too small to be correctly aligned with the underlying map.

I use the same CRS as the project's. WGS84.

image of the text

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the first few lines from the csv?  That would help to understand your problem.

Comment: Sounds like your project is in 3857, did you add an osm backdrop?

Comment: @IanTurton the back drop is OSM indeed.

Comment: @StuSmith I uploaded an image of the csv text. thank you

Comment: Is the first value East or North?

Comment: @AndreJ the first value is east. it should've been 044

Comment: @BERA I did edit the post. refresh it

Comment: @BERA but then I will have to write the same thing! it is 44.888762, 34.772662 and so on...

Comment: @IanTurton your question gave me the hint to look for it. the problem was the projection. EPSG:4326 solved it. but please, can you explain the reason this happened? thank you so much

Comment: @BERA I solved it with Ian's comment. apparently the projection of 3857 doesn't work. thank you mate for your patience!

Comment: Putting an *image* of your data in the question forces each of our volunteers to retype your data before they could help you. In the future, please place a snipped of the data itself in the question, as ASCII text.

Comment: @Vince I will, thank you! I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was adding the points in 3857 CRS, I changed it as Ian hinted to 4326 and it all the points snapped into place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the coordinates of one or more points are wrong. Try to open the table and sort the coordinates from the highest values to the smallest (descendant order) for latitude then longitude. If some values are out if range then just correct them or delete the row(s).

Comment: no, it was the projection as Ian Turton indicated. thank you for the effort.